# python get elements by checking keys in another list

Tags: python

I'd like to get a subset from a list, by checking if its key is in another list.

```
class object:
    def __init__(self, key, x, y):
        self.key = key
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

o1 = object(key=300, x=18.0, y=100.0)
o2 = object(key=301, x=12.0, y=1032.0)

x1 = object(key=100, x=28.0, y=2300.0)
x2 = object(key=101, x=43.0, y=332.0)
...


myobj = [o1, o2, o3]
objects = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, ... ]
```

suppose `o2.key == x3.key` and `o3.key == x6.key`, then gets `[o2, o3]`

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Can you add the exact data model and code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension of the form:

```
keys = [ x.key for x in objects ]
subset = [ x for x in myobj if x.key in keys ]
```

Although you may be better off adjusting your data into a dictionary, as the lookups will perform better on larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a list comprehension to get the result

```
result = [filter(lambda y: y.key == x.key, myobj) for x in objects]
```

EDIT:

this will return a list of list, which is not the anwser OP needed, it need an additional `reduce` to faltten the result

```
def intersect():
    o1 = {"key":300, "x":18.0, "y":100.0}
    o2 = {"key":500, "x":18.0, "y":100.0}
    o3 = {"key":600, "x":18.0, "y":100.0}

    x1 = {"key":300, "x":18.0, "y":100.0}
    x2 = {"key":300, "x":18.0, "y":100.0}

    myobj = [o1, o2, o3]
    objects = [x1, x2]

    result = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [filter(lambda y: y['key'] == x['key'], myobj) for x in objects])
    print result
```

Comment: Is this O(n^2), `len(objects)*len(myobj)`?

Comment: Had tried but the result is `[<filter object at 0x1916F970>, <filter object at 0x169B1130>]`.

Comment: I think this would give something different to the desired output, as it would effectively return a list of lists [[o2],[o3]] not [o2,o3] (in practice, a list of filter objects)

Comment: @Harvey yes this is O(n^2)

Comment: @Deqing sorry I didn't test it, I have update the answer, we need an reduce to flatten the result, the code has beed tested

Answer (score 0):

Can you add [`__hash__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and `__eq__()` methods to the object type? If so, you could use sets directly:

```
set(myobj).intersection(objects)
```

Even if you can't use `__hash__()`, you can use the keys:

```
subset_keys = set(o.key for o in myobj).intersection(o.key for o in objects)
subset = [ o for o in objects if o.key in subset_keys ]
```

Update: based on the updated question...

```
class object:
    def __init__(self, key, x, y):
        self.key = key
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __hash__(self):
        # must return an int
        return self.key
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return hash(self) == hash(other)
```

Comment: If you implement `__hash__` you should also implement `__eq__` and the two methods must be consistent. (EDIT: looks like you were busy adding that while I was typing the comment)

Comment: You were right to call me out on it. :) I had forgotten it.